# How to handle exceptions in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, rest, exception

I have simple html page where user chooses amounts of money he wants to withdraw, but i want want to show some kind a message if he want to withdraw more money than he has.

`HTML` page:

```
<body>
    <div> Choose one option</div>
    <button class="update-user-balance-btn" value="50">50</button>
    <button class="update-user-balance-btn" value="100">100</button>
    <button class="update-user-balance-btn" value="200">200</button>
    <button class="update-user-balance-btn" value="500">500</button>
    
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="update-user-balance.js"></script>
</body>
```

And this my update-user-balance.js file where i handle button action:

```
let updateUserBalanceBtn = $(".update-user-balance-btn");

updateUserBalanceBtn.on('click', function () {
let amountToUpdate = $(this).val();
let user = {
    "balance": amountToUpdate
};

let $insertXHR = $.ajax({
    method: "PATCH",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/user-rest-api",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(user),
    success: function (data) {
       // What can i do here?
    }
 });
});
```

This my rest controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user-rest-api")
public class UserRestController {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepo;
@Autowired
private User user;

@PatchMapping(consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void updateUser(@RequestBody User patchUser) { 
        if (patchUser.getBalance() < user.getBalance()) {
            user.setBalance(user.getBalance() - patchUser.getBalance());
             userRepo.save(user);
        } else{
           // what should i do here?
          }
    } 
}
```

What is proper way of solving this problem and handling exceptions?

Comment: you can use ControllerAdvice in spring boot to handle exceptions, make custom exception and throw it , and pass the required response from your controlleradvice

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a rest controller, it would make sense to return an appropriate http status code along with details to indicate that some business validation failed. In this case it looks more like a 409 status code.

```
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body(message);
```

Or as others have mentioned use a global exception handler to perform this.

On the jQuery side, add a error block to handle failure

```
error: function() {
          alert('handle error here');
}
```

Comment: I did and it worked, but now in jquery it goes in `error` tab regardless is user can or can not withdraw money. I put in if statement to return `ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.Ok).body(message);` and in else `ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body(message);` Why it's not entering `success` tab if user can withdraw money?

Comment: I would check the json returned in the response is a valid json. If the response if not a valid json, it will always goes to the error block.

In your case, the controller method is returning a void. You can change that to a @ResponseEntity and return a User object or handle the ajax call expect a text, instead of json.